# extract first sequence only from a fasta file

Tags: perl, loops, sequence, bioinformatics, fasta

I want to extract the first sequence only from a fasta file of multiple sequences.
I have this code below but i cant get the loops just right to work with one another.

```
while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    for (my $i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
        print $out_fh $line;
    }
}

close $out_fh;
```

I think its getting mixed up in the while loop but no matter what i try its not correct. I tried moving the for loop outside for example but it didnt work. Is it the type of loop?
Thanks very much for all pointers.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? I assumed there was one fasta record per line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each fasta record header starts with `>` and the sequence shouldn't ever have that character in it.  It should be safe to keep reading lines until you see the 2nd line that starts with `>`.

```
my $line = <$in_fh>;
#print first line no matter what
print $line;

while($line = <$in_fh>){
  #line must start with ">"
  unless( $line =~/^>.+/){
     print $line;
  }else{
    last;  #skip to the end
 }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

If you want just the first line of an input file, then you don't need a `while` loop.

```
my $line = <$in_fh>;
print $out_fh $line;
```

EDIT:

After researching the [FASTA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), I think it is sufficiently complicated enough that you shouldn't parse it manually. Instead, you should use [BioPerl](https://metacpan.org/release/BioPerl).

EDIT 2:

Here is a working example, using BioPerl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Bio::Seq;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $fasta_file = shift @ARGV or die "Usage: $0 FASTA_FILE\n";

my $seqin = Bio::SeqIO->new( -format => 'Fasta', -file => $fasta_file )
  or die "can't load fasta file: $fasta_file\n";

my $seqobj = $seqin->next_seq();

my $sequence = $seqobj->seq();

print $sequence;
```

Comment: Fasta records span multiple lines (although you wouldn't know that if you only read the OP question)

Comment: agree with use of BioPerl

Answer (score 3):

I know you want perl, but the awk solution is shorter:

```
awk '/^>/{if(N)exit;++N;} {print;}' in.fa
```

Comment: Not much. :P `perl -00 -ne '/(>[^>]+)/ && print $1' in.fa`